# How do I get a random image from a group of images?

Tags: python, image, random, window, pygame

How do I get an image from a group of images in pygame sprites? So far I got to this:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    img = pygame.image.load("house"+str(i)+".png").convert()
    img.set_colorkey(white)
    self.images.append(img)
```

But I'm not quite sure how to randomly collect an image from a list of images. How do I do this? And if possible how do I make it a chance of an image from that list of images like 1/10 of a chance that image will appear on the pygame window? Python 2.6, Pygame, windows 7

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a list of images bound to the name `self.images`.
If you want to randomly select one of them:

```
import random

random_image = random.choice(self.images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module of python and do your [`choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) from the available options.